# How to generate URL for SPA Page

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-router, html-framework-7

I've been doing research on this issue but I cannot find my answer. I am trying to create a group chat with Vue2 and F7, so I use GUID to pass to the chat page:

> this.value = 'http://localhost:8088/chat-group/' + this.groupId

However, the link doesn't work if I open it in a new tab. This is the error I am getting:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Below is the source file:

```
<template>
<f7-page :name="name">
<f7-navbar :title="title" :back-link="back" sliding>
    <f7-nav-right>
        <f7-link  href="#">Share</f7-link>
    </f7-nav-right>
</f7-navbar>

    <div class="content-block-title">Create New Chat Group </div>
    <div class="list-block media-list">
        <ul>
            <li>

                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-subtitle">Please enter your topic</div>
                        <div class="item-text">{{groupId}}</div>
                    </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="item-media"><a :href="chatGroupId"><qrcode-vue :value="value" :size="size" level="H"></qrcode-vue></a></div>

</f7-page>
</template>

<script>
    import QrcodeVue from 'qrcode.vue'

    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          title: 'Chat Group',
          name: 'Chat Group',
          back: 'Back',
          groupId: 'new',
          chatGroupId: '',
          responseHTML: '',
          joined: false,
          username: '',
          members: ['abc', 'cba'],
          newMessage: '',
          messages: [{'username': 'abc', 'message': 'hello'}, {'username': 'cba', 'message': 'world'}],
          status: '',
          value: '',
          size: 250
        }
      },
      mounted: function () {
        this.groupId = this.guid()
        this.value = 'http://localhost:8088/chat-group/' + this.groupId

        this.chatGroupId = '/chat-group/' + this.groupId + '/'
          console.log(this.value)

      },
      methods: {
        guid () {
          function s4 () {
            return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                      .toString(16)
                      .substring(1)
          }
          return s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() + s4() + s4()
        }
      },
      components: {
        QrcodeVue
      }
    }

</script>
```

I am also using App-Framework, and this is the routes.json file:

```
  {
    "path": "/chat-chinese/",
    "component": "ChatChinese.vue"
  },
  {
    "path": "/chat-english/",
    "component": "ChatEnglish.vue"
  },
  {
    "path": "/chat-group/:groupId/",
    "component": "ChatGroup.vue"
  },
  {
    "path": "/chat-groups/",
    "component": "ChatGroups.vue"
  }
```

Comment: Found a similar issue without answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145001/vue-router-firebase-navigate-with-direct-link#autocomment76614376

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a web server that supports rewriting URLs to a default (e.g. `index.html` for most Single-Page Apps). Since you're using Firebase already, you could configure and use `firebase serve` from the [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools). Just say `Y` to the question about rewriting all URLs to `index.html` when running `firebase init`.

There are plenty of other options available as well, but the key point is that this is a server-side issue, not something that can be solved with client-side code.

Comment: Firebase allows you to have rewrite and redirect but neither works:  "hosting": {
  // Add the "rewrites" section within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}